# Authentication using Api in Android app

Tags: java, android

Hello there is an Api which i have a username and a password

[image]

Now i want to create a user authentication in my app like this

[image]

In the api if i use the right username and password it returns me a token if not the token is null

Now my question is how to POST my username and the password to the api and how to GET the response (propably the token?) to see if the user is authenticated so he will go on to my Android app.Can you give me an example or telling me what should i search to accomplish this task ? Thank you for your help

Comment: Try to see different libraries like Retrofit or OkhttpClient

Comment: Retrofit is a good library. Find it here: http://square.github.io/retrofit/

Comment: thank you for your responses :)